# (CLOSED) Can't place image inside div container

Tags: html, css

**upd:** Noone found the solution, so I'll leave it here: for the image to successfully fit into div using object-fit property, you need to define height as well as the width of the image, otherwise, it won't work. Check my snippet below for a solution.

I'm trying to make a carousel on my page. I have a special div block for it with a class `.carousel` and I have a class `.carousel-entity` for each carousel element. I need an image to be placed inside a special div inside the carousel element which is called: `.carousel-image-holder`. But I don't want to crop an image manually, I rather want to use `object-fit: cover` on the image, so it will stick an image in the holder automatically.

**Problem:** everything loads just fine apart from the `.carousel-image-holder` and `.carousel-image`. When the prior div `.carousel-entity` changes size e.t.c., it doesn't apply to the holder. Moreover, the object-fit doesn't work as intended.

I will appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

```css
.container {
  background-color: royalblue;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel {
  max-width: 1080px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}

.carousel-entity {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.carousel-image {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.carousel-description {
  color: black;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-entity">
      <img class="carousel-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/328/600/200.jpg?hmac=vUUwo5NAN5eVJtmPoVnITBdWLD3Y4gXEROwi2m1IKts" />

      <div class="carousel-description">
        <h6>User</h6>
        <p>Post name</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-entity">
      <img class="carousel-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/328/600/200.jpg?hmac=vUUwo5NAN5eVJtmPoVnITBdWLD3Y4gXEROwi2m1IKts" />

      <div class="carousel-description">
        <h6>User</h6>
        <p>Post name</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-entity">
      <img class="carousel-image" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/231404/bd502155-a1c2-47e6-964e-bc0aaee31fde/s1200" />

      <div class="carousel-description">
        <h6>User</h6>
        <p>Post name</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-entity">
      <img class="carousel-image" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/1714257/pub_5d73b490f73d9d00ae3d3223_5d73b6571febd400ac931190/scale_1200" />
      <div class="carousel-description">
        <h6>User</h6>
        <p>Post name</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `width: 100%` to `.carousel-image`.

This will make it so that if the image is smaller become bigger, but if the image is bigger it will become smaller.

Code:

```css
.container {
  background-color: royalblue;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel {
  max-width: 1080px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}

.carousel-entity {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.carousel-image-holder {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.carousel-image {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%
}

.carousel-description {
  color: black;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-entity">
      <div class="carousel-image-holder">
        <img class="carousel-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/328/600/200.jpg?hmac=vUUwo5NAN5eVJtmPoVnITBdWLD3Y4gXEROwi2m1IKts" />
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-description">
        <h6>User</h6>
        <p>Post name</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-entity">
      <div class="carousel-image-holder">
        <img class="carousel-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/328/600/200.jpg?hmac=vUUwo5NAN5eVJtmPoVnITBdWLD3Y4gXEROwi2m1IKts" />
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-description">
        <h6>User</h6>
        <p>Post name</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-entity">
      <div class="carousel-image-holder">
        <img class="carousel-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/328/600/200.jpg?hmac=vUUwo5NAN5eVJtmPoVnITBdWLD3Y4gXEROwi2m1IKts" />
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-description">
        <h6>User</h6>
        <p>Post name</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-entity">
      <div class="carousel-image-holder">
        <img class="carousel-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/328/600/200.jpg?hmac=vUUwo5NAN5eVJtmPoVnITBdWLD3Y4gXEROwi2m1IKts" />
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-description">
        <h6>User</h6>
        <p>Post name</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is a good solution to my current problem, but if I place an image of another resolution the whole holder starts acting weird. That's why this problem can't be solved with adding width. I need something like object-fit: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the lines

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

to the carousel-image-holder div in your CSS file. Right now, you've adjusted the size of the image itself, but by doing this, you'll make sure carousel-image-holder is always as wide or large as carousel-entity, which should stretch it when the carousel-entity size is adjusted.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately, didn't work with images of different resolution(

Answer (score 0):

Just give the image a `max-width: 100%` and `height: auto;`

and you are good to go.

```
.carousel-image {
  object-fit: cover;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Edited. Based upon the desired output shown in the image. I think this is the best way to reach it. If that's not what you need do please let me know.

```css
.container {
  background-color: royalblue;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel {
  max-width: 1080px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}

.carousel-entity {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  width: 250px;
  /* height: 200px; */
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.carousel-image-holder {
  /* margin: 5px; */
  max-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.carousel-image {
  /* object-fit: cover; */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-description {
  color: black;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-entity">
      <div class="carousel-image-holder">
        <img class="carousel-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/328/600/200.jpg?hmac=vUUwo5NAN5eVJtmPoVnITBdWLD3Y4gXEROwi2m1IKts" />
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-description">
        <h6>User</h6>
        <p>Post name</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-entity">
      <div class="carousel-image-holder">
        <img class="carousel-image" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/231404/bd502155-a1c2-47e6-964e-bc0aaee31fde/s1200" />
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-description">
        <h6>User</h6>
        <p>Post name</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-entity">
      <div class="carousel-image-holder">
        <img class="carousel-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/328/600/200.jpg?hmac=vUUwo5NAN5eVJtmPoVnITBdWLD3Y4gXEROwi2m1IKts" />
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-description">
        <h6>User</h6>
        <p>Post name</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-entity">
      <div class="carousel-image-holder">
        <img class="carousel-image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/328/600/200.jpg?hmac=vUUwo5NAN5eVJtmPoVnITBdWLD3Y4gXEROwi2m1IKts" />
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-description">
        <h6>User</h6>
        <p>Post name</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is a good solution to my current problem, but if I place an image of another resolution the whole holder starts acting weird. That's why this problem can't be solved with adding width. I need something like object-fit: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/..

Comment: I see, I will look into that.

Comment: So, you want all the `.carousel-entity` divs to be at the same level as they are on the same line.

Comment: Yes! That's what I like it to be. I will show you a demo of how it should look like. Give me a sec

Comment: Great. That will help a lot.

Comment: I updated my answer please let me know if that's what you need or not.

Comment: It works, but the idea was that it doesn't stretch images, it just fits them and cropping them automatically

Comment: I really appreciate your help though

Comment: No problem man,  I hope someone with a better experience than me can help you out. ;)